# Panels disappearing after 1~2 secs using dojo framework

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using dojo to render the panels on UI. I am facing one issue. All the panels get rendered on UI for few seconds(around 1~2 secs). After that I am getting a blank white screen. Now if I want to see the panels I've to do dragging the splitter OR maximize/restore that pane. I.e. basically I need to play with the width so as to get back the disappeared panels.Please suggest some solutions over this.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can provide more information in your question, your code is better. Otherwise, it is hard to tell what exactly cause this issue.

But you can try add resize call of the container of your panels somewhere after you startup this container.

Comment: I am using dojo framework to load the panels. There are 4 panles to be rendered on UI. It renders the panel,but it displays it for few seconds. After that it gets disappeared. So I need to know the reason behind this issue. I tried to catch the event that might get called after all panels rendering. But I found that no events are being triggered after all the panels rendering.

Comment: And yeah, I tried to call the resize function that I have. This resize function basically read the width of the panels and then it just does addition of 2 pixels. And then it subtracts 2 pixels. Still this resize function is not able to render the disappeared panels.

Comment: It's better to have some codes post at here or can you try create a very simple example to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have defined following function and I am calling this method after panels get rendered.Function is : this.layoutExtreme = function(isCalledOnResize) { var tps = dijit.byId("contentPanelSet"); if (tps && tps.domNode && tps.domNode.style.display != "none") { var pixelHeight = tps.domNode.offsetHeight; if (pixelHeight > 2) { var pixelHeightP2 = pixelHeight+2; var pixelHeightM2 = pixelHeight-2; tps.domNode.style.height = pixelHeightM2; tps.domNode.style.height = pixelHeightP2;}}